# Check if Dropbox has synced

Tags: vb.net, dropbox

Before I look into this any further I just wondered if it's possible within VB.net to check if DropBox has synced?

Basically the program I have written uses DropBox to synchronize jobs to a Main computer which then ultimately process the zip file and deletes it. Once the job is processed a text file is re synced and the person who originally sent the job gets feedback as to its progress. All this works great. However, I would like to give an indication within the program itself so some of the less computer literate can see that DropBox has synced and they can safely turn off there laptops and head off home.

Has anybody any experience of this?

Comment: What have you tried?  You'll get more responses if you provide some code that you are struggling with instead of a broad idea of what you're trying to ultimately accomplish.

Comment: As I said I've not tried anything as yet but don't want to waste any time if its not going to be possible due to any restrictions in Dropbox. I'm just trying to see if anybody had accomplished this and then I can work to code it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Dropbox API to do the upload/download instead, at which point you'd know exactly when things had happened.

See https://www.dropbox.com/developers for information about the API.